# How to improve quality of baked textures

Tags: texturing, uv

I've baked all my characters textures in 4k expecting them to be pristine in quality, but they are all very pixilated and blurry. I've tried upscaling and changing the resolution but none of that worked. What should I do? (All images are PNG's)

Here's an example of my normal map. It should look like fabric but instead the fibers are all pixelated

[image]

Comment: Try increasing your render samples.

Answer (score 0):

Not only doesn't it look like fabric, the resolution is with 216x256 a factor 16 smaller than what 4k are supposed to be.

Did you specify the right dimensions (4096x4096) when creating the texture? The "Render Resolution" doesn't matter when baking - the size of the selected image (node) does.

I wouldn't try using an AI upscaler here. Aside from a possible mismatch between texture types like color/roughness/ect the normal map still describes a normalized vector, which likely won't be considered.

Comment: the reason this image is so small is because i took a snippet from the actual 4k image as it was too big to upload here. Also i couldn't find a good ai upscaler, they just made the image slightly brighter instead of fixing the quality